# I'm currently working on a scraper, but how do I scrape more than one thing?

Tags: php, html, web-scraping

I've been working on a scraper for the past few days and I was wondering if it was possible to scrape urls from "A" tags and echo them as well under the "$titles->nodeValue".

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents('https://webpage/apps.html');
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
if(!empty($html)){ 
    $doc->loadHTML($html);
    libxml_clear_errors(); 
  $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
  
  $title_row = $xpath->query('//div[@class="item-title"]');

  $button = $xpath->query('//a[@style="background: #F0F1F6; color: #007AFF; font-weight:bold;"]');

    if($title_row->length > 0){
        foreach($title_row as $titles){
            echo "<li>" . $titles->nodeValue . "</li>";
        }
    }
}
```